# Customize drag image on several element

Tags: javascript, jquery

i drag elements like this using jquery ;

```
<div id="drag-with-image" class="dragme">
    blabla 
</div>

<script>
    $(this).draggable({
        revert: false,   
        revertDuration: 0  
    });
</script>
```

And it works well.

What i'm trying to do is to customize the image when i drag an element.
I've done this :

```
<script>
document.getElementById("drag-with-image").addEventListener("dragstart",                   
function(e) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "http://kryogenix.org/images/hackergotchi-simpler.png";
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 0, 0);
}, false);
</script>
```

And it works well.

My probleme is : this code works for the element with the id "drag-with-image". I need to use this code with a lot of dragged elements by i can't replace the id by a class.

Do someone have a solution ?

Thanks

Comment: `getElementsByClassName('dragme')`.....?

Comment: i can't replace the id by a class

Already tried, that doesn't works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var draggables = document.querySelectorAll(".drag-with-image");
var index = 0, length = draggables.length;
for ( ; index < length; index++) {
    draggables[index].addEventListener("dragstart",                   
        function(e) {
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = "http://kryogenix.org/images/hackergotchi-simpler.png";
            e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 0, 0);
        }, false
    );
}
```

This will find all elements with the class 'drag-with-image' and attach the events to each one.